# Mailchimp advance form integration

Tags: html, mailchimp

Hello I have signup contact form that has a checkbox for news and updates of the site.
I'll be integrating the mailchimp for this
Any help?

Here is my HTML code

```
<form role="form" id="feedbackForm">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your First Name"/>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your first name.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Last Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your Last Name"/>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter your last name.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Email Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"/>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Company Name</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Enter your company name"/>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Message<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
                                              </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label for="selectbasic">How did you hear about us?</label>
                                                  <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Select</option>
                                                    <option value="Search Engine">Search engine</option>
                                                    <option value="Microsoft DPE">Microsoft DPE</option>
                                                    <option value="Microsoft Event">Microsoft event</option>
                                                    <option value="Social Media">Social media</option>
                                                    <option value="Word of Mouth">Word of mouth</option>
                                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Please keep me informed of kinectAPI product updates and news
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                              <img id="captcha" src="library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
                                              <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'library/vender/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false" class="btn btn-green btn-sm">Show a Different Image</a><br/>
                                              <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha_code" id="captcha_code" placeholder="For security, please enter the code displayed in the box." />
                                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter the code displayed within the image.</span>
                                              </div>

                                              <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a the security code.</span>
                                              <button type="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn btn-purple btn-md message-btn">Submit Message</button>
                                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Your going to need to be more specific in your question...I've actually integrated mail chimp signup with bootstrap... What exactly do you need help with ?

Comment: Oh. I want the checkbox to have a code which has a mailchim integrated. if user check the checkbox that he wants to receive news and updates from us, it will added on our list.

Comment: is there a way that user only click the checkbox and everything will follow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own custom form for creating new subscribers you'll need to post your data and interact with the mailchimp api found [Here](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php)

Although this is possible, the way mailchimp is setup... It makes adding subscribers much more simple. I'd recommend creating your form from there end and embedding it into your html... It is mobile friendly By the way... Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate users to Mailchimp then the simple way is to use Mailchimp embed forms. This is very easy and simple. Just put the embed code in your page and it start working.

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-my-signup-form-on-my-website/

Comment: is there a way here to just have a checkbox button saying "Please keep me informed of product updates and news" and it will trigger the mailchimp to add the email that was inputted on the form?

Comment: yeah you can create group on mailchimp with name "Please keep me informed of product updates and news" and this will show as a checkbox on embed form.

Comment: Other solution is you need small code of javascript in which if the checkbox is checked then the form is hit and the user subscribed to your given list.

Comment: what if I have my own html code and I'll just integrate the mailchimp code? like what I have downloaded on mailchimp MCAPI.class.php

Comment: yeah you can do this ... you can try or read this code https://github.com/ChimpChamp/naked-chimp this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that! Any other example which has a checkbox?

Comment: I exactly do the same work with the help of naked-chimp code. http://stage.newfrontierarmory.com/my-account/ you can see here checkbox "Subscribe To Our Newsletter" if user check this box then he subscribed on mailchimp.

Comment: But I really don't know how can I integrate the checkbox there and update my list once a user check it on my form

Comment: Well in your case you need to send ajax call if the checkbox is checked then send ajax call to some function where you get the user email and then subscribed to mailchimp. read this http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php